# What are the functions listed in these code examples?

Tags: python

Im really new to programming.  This is the first time Ive actually sought help for what Im trying to figure out.  Usually, with all of the help from this site I can figure out what I need.  This has me running in circles.  Below is a sample of some code for a module that belongs to much larger application.  I see it uses tkinter, and obviously Python.  Both of which im quite familiar with.  My main question is in regards to the ".browse()", ".fetch()" and ".put()" function calls.  I dont have anything else from the main application to go off of, so this is a shot in the dark.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is my first post so go easy.

```
record_clear = view.recordClear()
put_key = view.put(KEYFIELD, large_key)
filter = '{} LIKE "{}%"'.format(KEYFIELD, PREFIX)
browse = view.browse(filter, 0)
fetch = view.fetch()
```

Im not getting any errors as I cant actually run the full script without access to the main program its importing from.  This is just a snippet of the entire code that displays what Im trying to figure out.

Comment: These are methods of the `view` instance object. The question is, "what is a `view`?". We can't really tell unless you can show us where `view` is coming from.

Comment: I think this may help now that I have more information. Im not sure how to format the code to fit this section
def _get_last_forwards(view):
    """Get the last record by traversing all matching records.

    This is much less efficient than _get_last_backwards and should only be used
    as a fallback.
    """
    record_clear = view.recordClear()
    filter = '{} LIKE "{}%"'.format(KEYFIELD, PREFIX)
    browse = view.browse(filter)
    last = None
    while view.fetch() == 0:
        last = view.get(KEYFIELD)
    _debug("Get last forward found {}".format(last))
    return last

Comment: That looks like some kind of abstraction of database tables. `view` represents a specific table, resp. something like a cursor on it. `browse` on its own probably performs SELECT queries; in conjunction with a filter, the result set might be restricted to records meeting certain criteria. `put` might wrap an INSERT or, more likely, an UPDATE query, potentially allowing to pass an optional filter. `fetch` retrieves one record from the result of a `browse` call; `recordClear` clears the internal result cache to prepare for a new query. Just guessing, though :)

Answer (score 0):

The “view” is going to be a variable that is the instance of some class.  You probably know already how to create variables with a certain type in most languages, well in python a class can be a kind of like a type. A class is much more than a type though — it is a container definition that associates an organized blob of data with functions (called methods and properties) that operate on that data, and get things done using that data.

So, the “view” variable was previously set up to point to a newly allocated instance of some class.  The recordClear, put, browse and fetch methods change (mutate) and act upon the state of the data inside of the “view” variable.

To further explain how this class container idea is powerful — You could possibly somewhere else in the code have a “view2” variable with similar methods being called on it... those method calls on “view2” (e.g. a view2.filter() method call) would uniquely modify and act on the state inside “view2” and not affect the state of what’s in “view.”

There’s also that string with a method being called on it...  well, in python, strings are classes... and what’s being done on that line is an immediate instantiation of a string class and a format method is being called on that string to set up a filter.  That format method is going to drop the contents of KEYFIELD into the string replacing the first set of brackets and PREFIX in to replace the second set of brackets, and then will drop the resulting string into the “filter” variable.  You can read more about the string format method here:

https://pyformat.info/

Comment: So, my understanding of this is that the view has already been set in another part of the application and then a new instance is being made to modify the data inside without actually changing the data?  The KEYFIELD is a variable "CFORMNUM"

Comment: Well, “view” _is_ an instance, of a class (and we don’t know what that looks like internally), but we do guess that we are modifying it with at least the recordClear() and put() methods and are returning results using browse() and fetch() methods into the browse and fetch variables.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for a small example of what that might look like?